# Vim windows corrupted under tmux

Tags: macos, vim, tmux, nerdtree

Running Vim (7.4) in tmux on OSX causes the windows to corrupt like so:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2j79r711i4y6sb/Screenshot%202013-12-02%2014.50.53.png

This usually happens when I open Nerdtree. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a valid reason for not using the correct `TERM`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your terminal thinks the special Unicode characters that NERDTree is using in its tree (▾ and ▸) are two cells wide (like e.g. east-Asian Kanji characters), but they actually occupy only one cell. That messes up the display.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this, but you can avoid the problem (at least with NERDTree) by configuring "plain" symbols via

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrows = 0
```

Comment: It might be interesting to see if the problem goes away if he changes fonts in his terminal emulator?